# Calculate the average marginal effect (AME) in the multilevel regression with glmmTMB package

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis, glmmtmb

I am writing this message because I want to calculate the average marginal effects (AME) in order to be able to interpret an interaction resulting from a multilevel regression. However, I am finding that the vast majority of packages that are used for this purpose (marginal and marginaleffects) cannot be applied to regressions from the glmmTMB package. Any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. You can check `estimate_slopes` function from `modelbased` package. It supports `glmmTMB`. In `marginaleffects`, you can specify `vcov=FALSE` in `avg_slopes` and get the estimate without standard errors, or you can explicitly provide variance-covariance matrix (e.g., `vcov=vcov(mod)`). There is an ongoing (and quite helpful) discussion in this [issue](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/915) on github.